# Redirect and POST at the same time

Tags: php, html, post, get

I have a form and I don't do client-side validation other than `required` attribute. I'm doing the validation on the server side.

*lyrics/add.php*

```
<form action="../scripts/lyrics/submit_lyrics.php" id="lyricsForm" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Form data is processed in a seperate php file. Retrieving and validating the form data in the following way:

*scripts/lyrics/submit_lyrics.php*

```
$form_data = new FormData(["artist", "album", "song", "year", "track_no", "lyrics"], "sssiis");
$form_data->validate();
```

What the `validate` method does is

```
public function validate() {
    $valid  = $this->check_form_data($fields);
    $fields = implode(",", $fields);
    if (!$valid) {
        header("location: ".BASE."lyrics/add?status=error&problem=input&specifics=$fields");
        exit;
    }
}
```

check the form data and redirect the page (*scripts/lyrics/submit_lyrics.php*) to the form page (*lyrics/add.php*) with the information on validation (if it failed). Then I output an error message indicating that there's something wrong with the input using `GET` method.

I'm curious if I can do this using `POST`. I would need to modify this line

```
header("location: ".BASE."lyrics/add?status=error&problem=input&specifics=$fields");
```

make it redirect the page to `BASE."lyrics/add"` and also send the validation information using `POST` to that page. So I'd still be able output the validation error, but using `POST` instead of `GET`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Store values in a session.

Comment: Can use curl for this

Comment: there's http 307, which redirects with the same 'verb' used to invoke the original url. so if you post to "foo.php" and it 307's you to "bar.php", the browser will got a post to bar.php, not a get.

Comment: @MarcB That might be an idea, but I don't think he validates the data on bar.php again, so flashing into session is the better idea, as I can send the data to `bar.php` directly and bypass the validation.

Comment: I liked the session idea. Besides, it seems there's no other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using u_mulder's suggesion (storing values in a session), I've solved the problem in the following way:

*scripts/lyrics/submit_lyrics.php*

```
public function validate() {
    $valid  = $this->check_form_data($fields);  // check if input fields are valid
    $fields = implode(";", $fields);            // invalid input fields
    if (!$valid) {                              // not all fields are valid, so we return
        session_start();                        // start session
        if (!isset($_SESSION["problem"])) {     // making sure session variable doesn't exist
            $_SESSION["problem"]   = "input";   // error type: input, file_upload, db_insert, etc.
            $_SESSION["specifics"] = $fields;   // artist, album, etc. (for input)
        }
        header("location: ".BASE."lyrics/add?status=error"); // redirect to form page
        exit;
    }
}
```

*lyrics/add.php*

```
if (isset($_GET["status"])) {
    $status = $_GET["status"];
    switch ($status) {
        case "error":
            session_start();
            if (isset($_SESSION["problem"])) {
                $problem       = $_SESSION["problem"];
                $specifics     = explode(";", $_SESSION["specifics"]);
                $error_message = "There was an error.";
                switch ($problem) {
                    case "input":
                        $error_message = "Invalid input on the following fields:";
                        break;
                    // other cases ...
                }
                session_destroy();
                output("Error!", $error_message, $specifics);
            } else {
                // if the user reloads the page, session data is lost
                // but we're still in the error page "lyrics/add?status=error" and have no error to show
                // we either show an appropriate message or redirect to "lyrics/add"
                session_destroy();
                // output("Error!", "You're in the form validation error page, but there aren't any errors. Did you reload the page?");
                // header("location: ".BASE."lyrics/add");
                // exit;
            }
            break;
        case "success":
            // form submitted successfully
            break;
    }
} else {
    // show form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible because you are rewriting the request. The browser will always send a "GET" request in response to a redirect request, unless it receives a 307 request in which it will repeat the request using the same method and parameters. See [this related question on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect).

The workaround is to redirect to a new page with an embedded form that you generate, and have javascript POST that form for the user. It's an extra request but it's the only way to have the client make a second POST.